# Xml Schema validation, invalid valid content

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an xsd to validate an xml file, but I'm getting the error `Invalid content was found starting with element 'user'. One of '{user}' is expected.`

If I  change the namespace declaration to `xmlns:synchronisation="synchronisation"` and put `synchronisation:syncQueryMapping` as the root tag, but keep the rest the same, it is validated, but I do not understand why this works, why it is necessary and why the rest of the tags don't require it.

I can't seem to understand & fix the issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<syncQueryMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="synchronisation"
    xsi:schemaLocation="synchronisation syncQueryMappingSchema.xsd">

    <user>
        <tableName></tableName>
        <nameColumn></nameColumn>
        <passwordColumn></passwordColumn>
    </user>
    <group>
        <tableName></tableName>
        <nameColumn></nameColumn>
    </group>
    <userGroupMapping>
        <tableName></tableName>
        <userNameColumn></userNameColumn>
        <groupNameColumn></groupNameColumn>
    </userGroupMapping>

</syncQueryMapping>
```

The xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="1.0" targetNamespace="synchronisation" xmlns="synchronisation">

    <!-- JAXB Configuration -->
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                <jaxb:package name="synchronisation.implementation" />
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncUserType" >
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tableName" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nameColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="passwordColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="suspendStartDateColumn" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="suspendEndDateColumn" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncGroupType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tableName" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nameColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="typeColumn" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element type="typeColumnDataTypeType" name="typeColumnDataType" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="typeValue" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeColumnDataTypeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="INTEGER" />
            <xs:enumeration value="VARCHAR" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncUserTableJoinType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userKeyColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="mappingsForeignKeyColumn" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncGroupTableJoinType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="groupKeyColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="mappingsForeignKeyColumn" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncUserGroupMappingJoinType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="dbSyncUserTableJoinType" name="userTable" />
            <xs:element type="dbSyncGroupTableJoinType" name="groupTable" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dbSyncUserGroupMappingType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tableName" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userNameColumn" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="groupNameColumn" />
            <xs:element type="dbSyncUserGroupMappingJoinType" name="join" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Root element -->
    <xs:element name="syncQueryMapping">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="dbSyncUserType" name="user" />
                <xs:element type="dbSyncGroupType" name="group" />
                <xs:element type="dbSyncUserGroupMappingType" name="userGroupMapping" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added `xmlns="synchronisation"` to your XML document you are specifying that all nested elements without a prefix belong to that namespace (`syncQueryMapping` and `user`).

```
<syncQueryMapping 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="synchronisation"
    xsi:schemaLocation="synchronisation syncQueryMappingSchema.xsd">
    <user>
        ....
```

You need to add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` on the root element in your XML schema to indicate that all the elements in a XML document corresponding to this XML schema are namespace qualified.

```
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="1.0" 
    targetNamespace="synchronisation" 
    xmlns="synchronisation"
    elementFormDefault="qualfied">
```

Without that specified in order for your XML document to be valid only the global elements should be namespace qualfied.  This would mean you could not use a default namespace.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you! So is this declaring that elements without a namespace are qualified by this schema as default? Thanks again!

Comment: @TheBloodGuy - I have updated my answer, hopefully that will make it clearer.

Comment: Nearly all schemas specify elementFormDefault="qualified", you should treat it as boilerplate. Making the default in XSD the other way around was a silly mistake in the language design.